# Unbound voting with Schema.org

Tags: seo, schema.org, structured-data

I use [`SoftwareSourceCode`](http://schema.org/SoftwareSourceCode) structures in my pages, I include `aggregateRating` as such:

```html
<div itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/SoftwareSourceCode">
  <span itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
    <span itemprop="ratingValue">0</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

However, Google shows this out to me:

[image: Three errors in Google's SDTT]

The problem is that I do *not* have any specific min/max voting, it's a simple voting system where anyone can upvote/downvote by 1.

So my question is, what is the better alternative for this? Or how can I get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error (providing `ratingCount` or `reviewCount`) in the SDTT is about conforming to the guidelines from [Google’s Review rich results](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/reviews). As Google doesn’t seem to offer these rich results for the `SoftwareSourceCode` type, you can ignore it. Schema.org never requires a property.

The two following errors are given because you use "0" as `ratingValue`. If you don’t provide `worstRating` and `bestRating`, the values "1" and "5" are assumed (by Schema.org as well as Google).

(Note that `AggregateRating` is for the *average* rating. So when 5 users vote "+1", and no user votes "-1", the average is "1", not "5".)

Comment: While your answer explains the errors shown above, it doesn't provide an actual solution. Is there still anyway do provide a rating for Google, or do I need to remove the rating part entirely?

Comment: @OverCoder: If "for Google" means that you want to get the Reviews rich result, then no, there doesn’t seem to be a way, because `SoftwareSourceCode` is not supported by Google for this rich result (as said in my first paragraph). If you don’t care about the rich result, you can keep your markup like that, but then you should change the way you represent your ratings, so that you get an average value (e.g., between 0 to 1, or 1 to 5, or whatever makes sense for you).